# Using a calculated value in a query scope with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two Eloquent models, `Camp` and `Level`.

A `Camp` has a `start` and an `end` date field.

A `Level` has a `min_age` and a `max_age` integer field.

One `Level` is related to Many `Camps`

Using a query scope and a date parameter `$dob`, I would like to fetch a collection of `Camp`s where the age of someone born on `$dob` will fall between `min_age` and `max_age` on the `start` date.

In other words (some pseudo-code):

```
select * from Camps
   join Levels on Camps.level_id = Levels.id
where min_age <= (start - $dob)->toYears <= max_age
```

Is something like this possible using query scopes, and perhaps without using any raw queries? Maybe like this?

```
public function scopeAgeAppropriate($query, $dob) {
    return $query->join('Levels', 'Camps.level_id', '=' ,'Levels.id')
                 ->where('min_age', '<=', start->diffInYears($dob))
                 ->where('max_age', '>=', start->diffInYears($dob));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying through relationships `whereHas()` and using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to calculate the age on the fly:

Your scope will be:

```
public function scopeAgeAppropriate($query, $dob) {
    return $query->whereHas('levels',function($q) use ($dob) {
        return $q->where('min_age', '<=', \DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '{$dob}', Camps.start)"))
        ->where('max_age', '>=', \DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '{$dob}', Camps.start)"));
    })

}
```

Comment: OP wasn't clear on the database but I'm pretty sure with a Postgres adapter runs an `EXISTS` query when fetching models. This means `Camps` won't be available to query on unless I'm missing something? Please let me know

Comment: `whereHas` uses a sub select query to check on relationships, hence `Camps` table will be available for referencing.

Comment: Of course it does. For some reason I was thinking the exists subquery doesn't have access to the parent query columns. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: This worked well for me. I had to add single quotes around {$dob} for MySQL (which I should have specified) to accept the query. I was hoping for a solution which could use no raw queries and the Carbon library to calculate the time difference but this is sufficient. Thank you.